# Proving $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}\ln^3(n)}$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to prove that the following series is convergent:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}\ln^3(n)}$$

I tried the ratio test and the root test and both were inconclusive. Then I tried to calculate the integral $\int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x}\ln^3(x)}$ but I don't know how to integrate that function. How can I prove that this series converges?

Comment: Hint: $\exists k'$ such that $\ln^3(k) > 1$ for all $k>k'$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all $n \geq 3 > e$, $0 \leq \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}\ln^3(n)} \leq \frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}} $. By the comparison test, the series converges.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the comparaison test, together with the fact that$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N\setminus\{1,2\}):\frac1{n\sqrt n\log^3(n)}\leqslant\frac1{n\sqrt n}=\frac1{n^{3/2}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

You can just note that
$$
\frac{1}{n \sqrt{n} \ln^3 n}\leq \frac{1}{n \sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}, \quad n \ge 3.
$$

Since $\sum\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ converges, so does your series.